# WordPress media uploader javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have the code below which I have previously used to successfully open wordpress media uploader in my custom plugin page.

```
var custom_uploader;

jQuery('#uploadButton').click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    //Extend the wp.media object
    custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        title: 'Choose Image',
        button: {
            text: 'Choose Image'
        },
        multiple: false
    }); 
    //When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
    custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
        var attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
    alert(attachment.url);
    }); 
    //Open the uploader dialog
    custom_uploader.open(); 

});
```

This now fails with message "An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.". Is there something I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is this error occurring for all users or just to specific type of users?

Comment: Hi Yamu, this happens for admin users which are the only ones to have access to the feature.

Comment: Check if PHP GD library is installed or not.(you will find many links to check in google).

Comment: I don't understand how I need to use that library as the code was initially working? Is that set as a prerequisite for the media uploader?

Comment: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/an-error-occurred-in-the-upload-please-try-again-later-2

This might help you.

Comment: Thanks Yamu, but the thread is geared more for people who don't know what is causing the issue. I know, it is the code I am executing and I'm looking for help on that. The standard "Media" section work just fine but when doing this on my custom plugin page it fails.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60894/discussion-between-themba-clarence-malungani-and-yamu).